# While loop - break loop based on ID value

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, break, continue

I'd like to loop through and output all the records in my table but if the **$id** were to equal **4** or **6** I need it to append a string to the ID value.

My current code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM publications";
$sqlres = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlres)) {

$id = $row['id'];

echo $id;

}
```

How do I achieve this?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: something like `$id = ($id==4 || $id==6)? $id."string": $id;`?

Comment: @JCOC611 Make it an answer, it's correct! +1

Comment: absolutely perfect. many thanks for such a speedy and accurate reply.

Comment: @rsplak @user644978: I just made that an answer, your welcome!

Comment: @JCOC611 +1 as you were the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test for the values and echo something more like P.Martin said, or you can append it to the variable:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlres)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $id = ($id==4 || $id==6)? $id."string": $id;
  echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just test for the value of `$id`, and echo some additional information if that value is `4` or `6` :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlres)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo $id;
    if ($id == 4 || $id == 6) {
        echo 'something more';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your while loop you should put something like

```
if ($id == 4 || $id == 6)
   $id = $id . $myString;
```

before echoing it.